# Methods which calculates month count between 2 dates which works in contract with LocalDate#plusMonths method?

Tags: java, date, java-8, jodatime, localdate

I need to manipulate with dates according my task. To be precise I need to check that we have month difference between 2 dates as integer.  2 dates- input arguments. Result - boolean: `true` if month count is exact(without tail) `false` otherwise.
**For example:**

diff_months between `31.01.2018` and `28.02.2018` should be 1 month and it is possible combination.
`30.01.2018` and `28.02.2018` **:** 1 month without tail, so **ok**
`29.01.2018` and `28.02.2018` **:** 1 month without tail, so **ok**
`28.01.2018` and `28.02.2018` **:** 1 month without tail, so **ok**
`27.01.2018` and `28.02.2018` **:** 0 months

lets take another arguments:
`28.02.2018` and `28.03.2018` **:** 1 month without tail, so **ok**
`28.02.2018` and `29.03.2018` **:** 1 month +1 day, so **fail**
`28.02.2018` and `27.03.2018` **:** 0 month with tail, so **fail**

I found that java date api has special API for date calculation but from my point of view it works contradictory:

```
LocalDate.of(2018, 1, 31).until(LocalDate.of(2018, 2, 28), ChronoUnit.MONTHS); //  0     
LocalDate.of(2018, 1, 31).plusMonths(1); // but 2018-02-28
```

The second result is expected but firs - not. It looks really weird.

Can you please advise method for month count calculation between two dates which works in contract with the `LocalDate#plusMonths` method ?

Comment: Can you state your definition of month difference in plain English? Your examples are not clear. By the way, use standard ISO 8601 formats (YYYY-MM-DD) when presenting example dates here, for readability.  And what is a “tail” on a month?  And search Stack Overflow before posting. This Question is likely a duplicate. I’m voting to close as “unclear”.

Comment: @Basil Bourque, it is joda time format. It is not duplicate

Answer (score 1):

Expressing the difference between dates in calendar terms is ambiguous.  The `Period` between jan 31 and feb 28 can be "1 month 0 days" or "0 months 28 days".  Both answers are strictly correct.

If you want to implement your particular logic for determining if two dates are line up with `plusMonths`, java.time gives you all the tools.  First, get the number of months between dates without regard for days of the month and then use `plusMonths` to test:

```
boolean isExactMonths(LocalDate a, LocalDate b) {
    long months = ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(YearMonth.from(a), YearMonth.from(b));
    return a.plusMonths(months).equals(b);
}
```

Comment: *ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between("31.01.2018", "28.02.2018")* returns 0 but I expect 1

Comment: @gstackoverflow Correct, but the code in the answer, `ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(YearMonth.from(a), YearMonth.from(b))` uses `YearMonth` and therefore returns 1 as you said you expected. I tested this code with the seven examples from your question. Output agrees without put from my answer, which I believe agrees with what you intended. Plus this code is *much* more elegant than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Joda time works as expected:

```
Months.monthsBetween(org.joda.time.LocalDate.parse("2018-1-31"),org.joda.time.LocalDate.parse("2018-2-28")).getMonths() //1
```

Comment: I deleted my comment. I had not noticed the Question is specifically addressing *Joda-Time* as well as *java.time*.